# What is the intuition behind weights and biases in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am having a hard time trying to understand what weights and biases mean in a neural network and how do they help the neural network make right prediction . I know how weights and biases are changed by backtracking but what does their value mean  and what is it's significance.

Comment: Weights are factors, biases are addends. Both are parameters in a non-linear model. Beside that, there's hardly a need for a more intuitive approach imho.

Comment: Do you know what the parameters do in a linear regression? It would benefit you immensely to learn what the parameters (including the intercept) mean in a simple linear regression. A neural network is, in some sense, a big web of linear regression models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each machine learning model has some features $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$. Those features may come from data, or be generated by a model itself (output of a previous layer of a neural network). Different models have different ways of using those features to learn patterns from the features and be able to make predictions. Some models, like [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), [generalized linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) (including [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression)), [support-vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine), or [neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) make the predictions by using at some point [linear combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) of the features

$$
\boldsymbol{w}^T\mathbf{x} + b = w_1 x_1 + w_2 x_2 + \dots + w_k x_k + b
$$

we call the parameters that we *multiply* the features with $\boldsymbol{w} = (w_1, w_2, \dots, w_k)$ *weights* and the parameters that we *add* *biases* $b$ to them. You can also see weights being called just *parameters* (this may include biases as well), and the *bias* term in regression models (linear regression, GLM's) is traditionally called an *intercept*.

Weights control how strongly the feature would influence the output (by multiplying it by a value) and biases help to ensure that the result is not too big or too small on average by moving it up (adding a positive constant) or down (adding a negative constant, so subtracting a constant). You [usually want to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7948/when-is-it-ok-to-remove-the-intercept-in-a-linear-regression-model) use the bias term in the model.

This is a basic building block often used in machine learning. Many models follow linear combinations of features with non-linear functions that transform them (GLM's, SVM's, neural networks). Some models (neural networks) can use such blocks many times in different places. Finally, there are models using nonlinear functions (e.g. [nonlinear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression)) where weights are the learned parameters of more complicated functions.